# Ubuntu Software Center not loading through VNC

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-14.04, vncserver

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty in which I am not able to open `Ubuntu Software Center` through VNC Client. After clicking on `Application Menu >> System >> Ubuntu Software Center` through RealVNC client, it is just not getting opened.

When I run `software-center` from terminal, it says:

```
vnc@ip-172-31-12-90:/$ software-center
2015-03-18 13:02:47,361 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/netstatus.py', 122, '__init_network_state')'
2015-03-18 13:02:47,361 - root - WARNING - failed to init network state watcher 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files'
2015-03-18 13:02:47,540 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/netstatus.py', 144, 'test_ping')'
2015-03-18 13:02:47,540 - root - INFO - Attempting one time ping of screenshots.ubuntu.com to test if internet connectivity exists.

(software-center:24120): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

(software-center:24120): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
2015-03-18 13:02:47,619 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'

(software-center:24120): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

(software-center:24120): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

(software-center:24120): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
2015-03-18 13:02:47,695 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/netstatus.py', 160, 'test_ping')'
2015-03-18 13:02:47,695 - root - INFO - ping output: 'Internet connection available!
PING screenshots.ubuntu.com (91.189.94.41) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from backoo.canonical.com (91.189.94.41): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=145 ms

--- screenshots.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 145.333/145.333/145.333/0.000 ms
'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 130, in <module>
    app = SoftwareCenterAppGtk3(options, args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 338, in __init__
    self.icons)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/appmanager.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.oauth_token = helper.find_oauth_token_sync()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/ubuntusso.py", line 141, in find_oauth_token_sync
    sso.find_credentials()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/login_impl/login_sso.py", line 74, in find_credentials
    self.proxy.find_credentials(self.appname, self._get_params())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken
```

Please guide.
Thanks

Comment: you must write in the terminal:
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
and then press enter, it will reset your software center.

Comment: @vembutech I tried doing that multiple times, it didn't helped as the issue was with the permission. Below solution worked for me. Thanks bdw :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it myself. I just had to change the ownership of the `/run/user/1000` to my VNC user i.e. `vnc`. Below is the command to do it:

```
sudo chown -R vnc:vnc 1000/
```

This solved the problem.

Hope that helps someone!

Thanks